# Only show a column in a table according to user preference and hide other columns

Tags: php, jquery

Originally,Regardless of the type of language,three columns will be display in the table, each display different languages of message, each saved into different column in the database

```
<td><textarea name="traditionalmessage[]" ><?php echo $row['traditionalmessage'];?></textarea> </td>

<td><textarea name="simplifiedmessage[]" ><?php echo $row['simplifiedmessage'];?></textarea> </td>

<td> <textarea name="engmessage[]"><?php echo $row['engmessage'];?></textarea> </td>
```

Now on the display page, i want to display only one column depends on the type of language in the db  eg.if the language is ENG, only the eng message will be shown, and other column  will be hidden, can it be done with php if else or does it invloves jquery

I have tried the if else,but it doesnt work.Any thoughts. Thanks

```
<td><textarea name="traditionalmessage[]"><?php 

if($row['language']=='tra'){
echo $row['traditionalmessage'];}?></textarea> 

<textarea name="simplifiedmessage[]"><?php 

 if($row['language']=='sim'){
 echo $row['simplifiedmessage'];}?></textarea> 

<textarea  name="engmessage[]" ><?php 

if($row['language']=='ENG'){

echo $row['engmessage'];?></textarea> </td>
```

Comment: Do you want to have just one textarea on the row? Or two empty ones plus the one which has text inside?

Comment: one textarea will be display on the screen

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette : one follow up with your solution, now only one column which means only one language of the message is being saved. Is there any way to save the other two columns that dont display on the screen as well ? Now i can only saved null into the db for the other two columns Many thanks

Comment: Hi Tam, I just don't know how you save it. You did not post any code about that. You should open a new question about this... But since the info comes from the database.... Why do you need to save it again?

Comment: it's like an edit page, it display data from db then update it back to the database. I hv open a new question.Please have a look.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166855/how-to-update-3-tables-columns-while-only-one-column-is-visible-to-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PHP code below find `$row['language']` content ("tra","sim" or "eng") in the `$possibleLang` array and gets the index back in `$index`.

This index makes the relationship between the "short language name" and the "long" one.

```
<?php
$possibleLang = ["tra","sim","eng"];
$testAreaField = ["traditionalmessage","simplifiedmessage","engmessage"];
$treatmentName = ["treatmentname1","treatmentname2","treatmentname3"];
$treatmentNameSuffix = ["下一個注射期為","下一个注射期为","Next injection period will be"];

$index = array_search($row['language'],$possibleLang);
?>

<td>
  <textarea name="<?php echo $testAreaField[$index]; ?>[]" data-value="<?php echo $row[$treatmentName[$index]] . $treatmentNameSuffix[$index]; ?>">
    <?php echo $row[$testAreaField[$index]]; ?>
  </textarea>
</td>
```

Comment: ,may i ask one more thing, within the textarea,there's 3 data-value for jquery features.   1.data-value="<?php echo $row['treatmentname1'].'下一個注射期為';?>" 2. data-value="<?php echo $row['treatmentname2'].'下一个注射期为';?>"  3. data-value="<?php echo $row['treatmentname3'].'Next injection period will be';?>" . I've tried to integrate it in the code but fail, any insight? Many thanks!

Comment: You just can't have the same attribute name 3 times. Try something like `data-value1`, `data-value2` and `data-value3`. ;) Or merge the 3 text values into one `data-value`...

Comment: Ho... Is it about having one of the three only? Like about the language?

Comment: Btw this is within the message

Comment: Using the same `$index`, you just needed two additionnal arrays. Then it is in the `data-value`attribute, ready to be picked-up by jQuery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153840/discussion-between-tam-and-louys-patrice-bessette).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<td>
 <?php if($row['language']=='tra'){ ?>
  <textarea name="traditionalmessage[]"><?php echo $row['traditionalmessage'];}?></textarea>
 <?php } ?>

 <?php if($row['language']=='sim'){?>
  <textarea name="simplifiedmessage[]"><?php echo $row['simplifiedmessage'];}?></textarea>
 <?php } ?>

 <?php if($row['language']=='ENG'){?>
  <textarea  name="engmessage[]" ><?php echo $row['engmessage'];?></textarea> 
 <?php } ?>
</td>
```