# How to update 3 tables columns while only one column is visible to the page

Tags: php, mysql

This is a table column that display message depends on user preferred language choice in the DB. eg if preferred language is ENG only the eng
message will show
PS: in the database, there's 3 column storing 3 types of message of different languages

```
 <?php
 $possibleLang = ["繁體","简体","ENG"];
 $testAreaField = ["traditionalmessage","simplifiedmessage","engmessage"];
 $treatmentName = ["vaccinename1","vaccinename2","vaccinename3"];
 $treatmentNameSuffix = ["\n下一個注射期為:","\n下一个注射期为:","\nNext 
 injection period will be:"];

 $index = array_search($row['language'],$possibleLang);
 ?>
<td>
<textarea  rows="3" cols="18" class="url" name="<?php echo 
 $testAreaField[$index]; ?>[]" data-value="<?php echo 
 $row[$treatmentName[$index]] . $treatmentNameSuffix[$index]; ?>"><?php echo 
 $row[$testAreaField[$index]]; ?>
 </textarea>
 </td>
```

This table is at an edit page that displays data from DB and also updates data back to the DB.

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  foreach ($_POST['patientid'] as $index => $patientid) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'][$index]);
    $data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($patientid);
    $data17 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['patienthkid'][$index]);

    $data2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vaccineid'][$index]);
    $data5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vaccinename3'][$index]);
    $data6 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['totalnoofinjection'][$index]);
    $data7 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nthinjection'][$index]);
    $data8 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date'][$index]);
    $data9 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nextdate'][$index]);
    $data10 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['skip'][$index]);
    $data11 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['language'][$index]);
    $data12 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['traditionalmessage'][$index]);
    $data13 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['simplifiedmessage'][$index]);
    $data14 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['engmessage'][$index]);
    $data15 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status'][$index]);
    $data16 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nurse'][$index]);


   if ($data12 != null) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE patientvaccinedetail SET patientid 
   ='$data1',patienthkid 
   ='$data17',vaccineid='$data2',vaccinename3='$data5', 
    totalnoofinjection='$data6',nthinjection='$data7',
    date='$data8',nextdate='$data9',skip='$data10',language='$data11',
    traditionalmessage='$data12',status='$data15',nurse='$data16' WHERE 
    id=$id")   or die(mysql_error());
     }
    else if ($data13 != null) {
   mysql_query("UPDATE patientvaccinedetail SET patientid 
    ='$data1',patienthkid 
   ='$data17',vaccineid='$data2',vaccinename3='$data5', 
  totalnoofinjection='$data6',
    nthinjection='$data7',date='$data8',nextdate='$data9',
   skip='$data10',language='$data11',
   simplifiedmessage='$data13',status='$data15',nurse='$data16' WHERE 
    id=$id")   or die(mysql_error());
    }
  else if ($data14 != null) {
  mysql_query("UPDATE patientvaccinedetail SET patientid 
  ='$data1',patienthkid ='$data17',vaccineid='$data2',
  vaccinename3='$data5', totalnoofinjection='$data6',
    nthinjection='$data7',date='$data8',nextdate='$data9',
   skip='$data10',language='$data11',
   engmessage='$data14',status='$data15',nurse='$data16' WHERE id=$id")
   or die(mysql_error());
    }

    }
    }
```

The issues are whenever I click save and `only one` column of the message is SAVED, other two column are updated as NULL in the database. The desired outcome is the update both 3 columns while only 1 column is visible to the page.
Any idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you check if your variables have data?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not update columns which are not being targeted for update.  For example, if the traditional message were selected, then you would update only this column.  I would probably use separate queries here.

```
foreach ($_POST['patientid'] as $index => $patientid) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'][$index]);
    $data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($patientid);
    $data2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['traditionalmessage'][$index]);
    $data3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['simplifiedmessage'][$index]);
    $data4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['engmessage'][$index]);

    if ($data2 != null && $data2 != '') {
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET patientid ='$data1',
          traditionalmessage='$data2' WHERE id=$id")   or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else if ($data3 != null && $data3 != '') {
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET patientid ='$data1',
          simplifiedmessage='$data3' WHERE id=$id")   or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else if ($data4 != null && $data4 != '') {
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET patientid ='$data1',
          engmessage='$data4' WHERE id=$id")   or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Note that I believe you are using a very old and deprecated PHP API for MySQL.  For starters, it would benefit you a lot by using prepared statements.

Comment: hi,i have tried to update my code with your solution, but for some reason, the outcome is same as before, the other 2 column is still update as null, please take a look, thank you

Comment: Check for both null and empty string.